# Solving cos(x)=x Algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I think a graphical approach is the best way, but can algebra be used? With IVT, from x:[0,1] a solution must exist.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for an exact solution? or an approximate solution or just existence of a solution?

Comment: If you have an equation mixing together algebraic and transcendental functions, you will have to solve them numerically using something like the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), or [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Indeed, the IVT can be used to guarantee a solution exists in some interval, but you aren't going to be able to find an exact solution for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments and answers, you need a numerical method such as Newton.

Consider the function $$f(x)=x-\cos(x)\qquad f'x)=1+\sin(x)$$ The iterates will be given by
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n \sin (x_n)+\cos (x_n)}{1+\sin (x_n)}$$ You can have a very good starting point building the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of the function at $x=0$; this would give
$$f(x)\approx \frac{-1+\frac{7 }{6}x+\frac{1}{4}x^2 } { 1-\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2}$$ and then $x_0=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{85}-7\right)$.

Now, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.73984815243096243667 \\
 1 & 0.73908526166480706885 \\
 2 & 0.73908513321516428479 \\
 3 & 0.73908513321516064166
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

**Edit**

For the fun of it, let us build the sama Pade approximant around $x=\frac \pi 4$. This will give as solution
$$4 \left(48+34 \sqrt{2}+7 \pi \right)x_0=$$ $$-720-408 \sqrt{2}+\pi  \left(36+46 \sqrt{2}+7 \pi \right)+4 \sqrt{65976+45744
   \sqrt{2}-3 \pi  \left(1328+940 \sqrt{2}+\left(131+62 \sqrt{2}\right) \pi
   \right)}$$ which is $\approx 0.73908513347523013264$. Quite close, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

No, in general only approximate solutions can be found for such equations. An algebraic, closed-form solution is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is transcendental in nature. It has to solved only numerically. Pressing $\cos $ button even in a hand calculator continuously iterates an input raw number to a solution.